# asp mvc reference errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I changed Target Framework version from 4.5 to 4 and rebuild whole solution. and it showing errors on attributes such as 
**[HttpPost]** 
also showing errors in Controllers with message

> The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

when I click all of this errors visual studio not fixing this errors and after click, clicked error is dissappearing, But when I run project It shows me this errors again. 
[image]

Comment: I don't remember in which version of the framework you have access to this annotation...the error is clear: the assembly does not have the namespace `Mvc`...did you try to change the `[HttpPost]` by `System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost`? also check the references on your project and make sure you have `System.Web.Mvc` there

Comment: There are no error after when I click some error and shows file. but after rebuild it shows me an errors again. it's not about references

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to install (or reinstall) NuGet package [`Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/).
2. Ensure that missed references are listed in `References` of your project and add references if they are not presented.

This is applicable for some other ASP.NET dlls, for example [`System.Web.Optimization`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization)